# PHP row navigation button switch always clears variable before running

Tags: php, html, button, mysqli, row

I am working on a program that gets values from a database and spits out one row at a time into a form text output. To see the different rows there are navigation buttons that will change the current row you are looking at. Everything works except for the buttons which get cleared and reinitialized every time you press one of them. There are four of these buttons, a "First", "Previous", "Next", and "Last" which set the number that is supposed to control the current row to the respective value for each button.

Here is the section that isn't working:

`

```
if(isset($result)){
    $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if(isset($button_value)){
        echo "After isset(button_val) in buttons, val = ".$button_value."<br>";
        if(isset($_GET['table_nav'])){
            $button_ch = $_GET['table_nav'];
            switch($button_ch){
                case "First":
                    unset($button_ch);
                    echo "button_value in, before = ".$button_value."<br>";
                    $button_value = 0;
                    echo "button_value in = ".$button_value."<br>";
                    break;
                case "Previous":
                    unset($button_ch);
                    if($button_value > 0){
                        echo "button_value in, before = ".$button_value."<br>";
                        $button_value--;
                        echo "button_value in = ".$button_value."<br>";
                        break;
                    }else{
                        echo "Invalid button action. No previous rows.<br>";
                        break;
                    }
                    break;
                case "Next":
                    unset($button_ch);
                    if($button_value < $rows){
                        echo "button_value in, before = ".$button_value."<br>";
                        $button_value++;
                        echo "button_value in = ".$button_value."<br>";
                        break;
                    }else{
                        echo "Invalid button action. No next rows.<br>";
                        break;
                    }
                    break;
                case "Last":
                    unset($button_ch);
                    echo "button_value in, before = ".$button_value."<br>";
                    $button_value = $rows - 1;
                    echo "button_value in = ".$button_value."<br>";
                    break;
                default:
                    unset($button_ch);
                    echo "Error, invalid row navigation button value<br>";
            }
            echo "button val after set by case = ".$button_value;
        }//*/
    }
} else {
    echo "ERROR in result";
}`
```

Pressing either the "First" or "Previous" buttons sets the button_value (being used to keep track of the current row) to 0, pressing the "Next" button sets button_value to 1, and pressing the "Last" button sets the value to the maximum number of rows for the selected table.

I really can't figure out what's going on here. If there is any more of the code needed to help figure this out I can supply it but I didn't want to post all 226 lines of code.

The larger chunk of PHP code is included below:

```
<?php
    global $table_array;
    //global $button_value;
    $table_array = array();
//* 
    if(!isset($button_value)){
        $button_value = 0;
        echo "reset the undecfined var button_value <br>";
    }//*/ 

    //$result = get_table($_GET["table_name"], $connection_to_mysql);
    if(isset($_GET["table_name"])){
        $table = $_GET["table_name"];
        //echo "table name is ".$table."<br><br>";
        $result = get_table($table, $connection_to_mysql);
        $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        list($table_array, $table_cols) = parse_result($result, $table);
        }

        //The button handling section
        if(isset($result)){
            $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
            if(isset($button_value)){
                if(isset($_GET['table_nav'])){
                    $button_ch = $_GET['table_nav'];
                    switch($button_ch){
                        case "First":
                            unset($button_ch);
                            $button_value = 0;
                            echo "button_value in = ".$button_value."<br>";
                            break;
                        case "Previous":
                            unset($button_ch);
                            if($button_value > 0){
                                $button_value--;
                                break;
                            }else{
                                echo "Invalid button action. No previous rows.<br>";
                                break;
                            }
                            break;
                        case "Next":
                            unset($button_ch);
                            if($button_value < $rows){
                                echo "button_value in, before = ".$button_value."<br>";
                                $button_value++;
                                echo "button_value in = ".$button_value."<br>";
                                break;
                            }else{
                                echo "Invalid button action. No next rows.<br>";
                                break;
                            }
                            break;
                        case "Last":
                            unset($button_ch);
                            $button_value = $rows - 1;
                            echo "button_value in = ".$button_value."<br>";
                            break;
                        default:
                            unset($button_ch);
                            echo "Error, invalid row navigation button value<br>";
                    }
                    echo "button val after set by case = ".$button_value;
                }//*/
            }
        } else {
            echo "ERROR in result";
        }
    ?>
```

If the section of code

```
if(!isset($button_value)){
        $button_value = 0;
        echo "reset the undefined var button_value <br>";
    }
```

isn't included at the top, then the variable "button_value" is always unset before each switch statement hit.

Oh, and here's the HTML for the buttons:

```
<form action='' method="GET">
    <table>
        <tr>
            &nbsp;<input id="button_first" type="submit" name="table_nav" value="First">
        </tr>
        <tr>
            &nbsp;<input id="button_previous" type="submit" name="table_nav" value="Previous">
        </tr>
        <tr>
            &nbsp;<input id="button_next" type="submit" name="table_nav" value="Next">
        </tr>
        <tr>
            &nbsp;<input id="button_last" type="submit" name="table_nav" value="Last">
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out a solution. By using a session global variable I could make the variable stop resetting to zero. So I put this at the top of my code:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION["button_value"])){
    $_SESSION["button_value"] = 0;
}
```

After this I updated the button management section of my code to utilize the session global:

```
//The button handling section
if(isset($result)){
    $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    //echo "Between isset(result) and isset(button_val) in buttons, rows = ".$rows."<br>";
        if(isset($_GET["table_nav"])){
            $button_ch = $_GET["table_nav"];
            $button_value = $_SESSION["button_value"];
            switch($button_ch){
                case "First":
                    unset($button_ch);
                    //echo "button_value in, before = ".$_SESSION["button_value"]."<br>";
                    $_SESSION["button_value"] = 0;
                    break;
                case "Previous":
                    unset($button_ch);
                    if($button_value > 0){
                        //echo "button_value in, before = ".$_SESSION["button_value"]."<br>";
                        $_SESSION["button_value"] = $button_value - 1;
                        break;
                    }else{
                        echo "Invalid button action. No previous rows.<br>";
                        break;
                    }
                    break;
                case "Next":
                    unset($button_ch);
                    if($button_value < $rows - 1){
                        echo "button_value in, before = ".$_SESSION["button_value"]."<br>";
                        $_SESSION["button_value"] = $button_value + 1;
                        break;
                    }else{
                        echo "Invalid button action. No next rows.<br>";
                        break;
                    }
                    break;
                case "Last":
                    unset($button_ch);
                    //echo "button_value in, before = ".$_SESSION["button_value"]."<br>";
                    $_SESSION["button_value"] = $rows - 1;
                    break;
                default:
                    unset($button_ch);
                    echo "Error, invalid row navigation button value<br>";
            }
            //echo "button val after set by case = ".$_SESSION["button_value"];
        }
}else{
    echo "ERROR in result";
}
```